# How to post new object to the existing json (clientside ReactJS + server side NodeJS and Express)

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express

Pretty new with NodeJS and Express but want to figure out it is possible to add new objects after loading api via client side. So in the first place it should load the api via server-side which contains the existing  objects and output on the client side, and when that is loaded I want to add new objects that I post via server side. So the new posted object should be added added to the json.

*Client Side*

```js
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

export const App = () => {
  const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState("");
  const [posts, setPosts] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const headers = { "Content-Type": "application/json" };
    try {
      const getData = async () => {
        const result = await axios.get('http://localhost:5000', headers);
        console.log(result.data);
      };
      getData();
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  }, []);

  const postReview = async value => {
    const headers = { "Content-Type": "application/json" };
    let data = {
      name: value
    };
    try {
      const getData = async () => {
        const result = await axios.post('http://localhost:5000/songs', data, headers);
        console.log(result.data);
      };
      getData();
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };

  const submitReview = () => {
    postReview(inputValue);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <input
        placeholder="Place review"
        onChange={e => setInputValue(e.target.value)}
      />
      <button onClick={() => submitReview()}>Send</button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

*Server Side*

```js
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
const axios = require('axios');
const app = express();
const port = 5000;

app.use(cors({ origin: '*' }));

app.use(express.json());

app.get("/", async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    const { data } = await axios.get('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/XiteTV/frontend-coding-exercise/main/data/dataset.json');
    res.status(200).send(data.videos);
  } catch (ex) {
    res.status(500).send(data.videos);
  }
});

app.post('/songs', async (req, res) => {
  console.log(reviews.length);
});
```

Comment: Use query parameters. For example GET /domain.xyz/posts?limit=10

Answer (score 0):

I didn't understand what you meant, but I think you want to add more objects to the list of posts, if so, use the following:

```
setPosts([
   ...posts,
   {
      //New post object
   }
])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can post directly in their API.

```js
const postReview = async review => {
    const headers = {
      "content-type": "application/json",
      "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"
    };
  
    // axios post request to that api
    const response = await axios
                            .post('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts',
                            {review},
                            {headers});
   
  };
```

They described this on their site. [Further read](https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/guide/)

Comment: Ok some urls gives you cors error which can only be solved on the backend, so how you going to deal with that?

Comment: you can put Heroku cors anywhere URL before your url.

So, instead of requesting http://example.com, you will request https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/http://example.com. CORS Anywhere will then make the request on behalf of your application, and add CORS headers to the response so that your web application can process the response.

it will solve that cors issue.